# java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6D78204C4D54483C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0

Tags: java

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6D78204C4D54483C, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0

Code: 

     guru99Workbook= new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
     Sheet sh = guru99Workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
     int totalNoOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum()- sh.getFirstRowNum();
     System.out.println(totalNoOfRows);
```

Please help me to solve this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The File you are trying to access isn't really a .xls file even though the extension may indicate that it is. Open the file in Excel and do "Save As" and then try to access the file. You should be fine. GoodLuck!

Comment: In my case. i am automatically downloading one xls file from my application and try to open the downloaded file. so i am not able to edit it manually and saved. Will you have any other option for this. @ankit MISHRA